# php. necesito ayuda para poder bloquear un contenido dependiendo si se inicia sesión

Tags: php

buenas noches, soy nuevo en la comunidad, mucho gusto!. necesito ayuda con un código en mi pagina web. www.sintoniadeinclusion.com
no puedo pegar el codigo aca porque no se como hacer para que no me lo reconosca como codigo de página. aclaro, soy una persona ciega, por eso no me doy cuenta donde puedo o como aplicar el codigo de forma tal de que se vea como codigo en si, por eso dejo la pagina para ver si una persona amablemente puede entrar a la misma y echarle un vistaso y ayudarme.
la cuestión, es que yo cree un sistema de usuario, por eso el sesion star en el prinsipio de la pagina. pero quiero ocultar el editar y el borrar que están debaj de una noticia en la vajo  el encabezado que dice justamente noticias. ya lo hise en 2 paginas mas, una para suvir la noticia, y otra para editarla. pero en esta no me deja aplicar no se porque. estaría agradesido si alguien me podría hayudar. gracias!

Comment: Hola Lucas, podrías copiar el código de todos modos, ya que los colaboradores pueden editarte el post y colocartelo como código, ya que siempre es útil saber qué has intentado

Answer (score 1):

Con el login creas una variable de Session que te contenga los datos de usuario, ahora en el index de tu pagina deberias tener algo que te valide si esta el usuario logueado y que tiene permisos de administrador y luego muestre las opciones editar y borrar, y si no esta logeado o es un usuario normal que no las muestre:

```
<?php
$log = $_SESSION['User'];
if(isset($_SESSION['User'])&& $log['User_Type'] == 'Admin')
{
  echo'<a href="#">Editar</a>';
  echo'<a href="#">Borar</a>';
}else{

}
?>
```

Para crear la sension y que contenga varios datos entre ellos el tipo de usuario si es administrador o usuario normal, en donde haces la consulta para el login debes almacenar esos datos en la sesion usando un arreglo:

```
$log=array('User_email' =>$Email,
'User_Nom' =>$Nombre,
'User_Ape' =>$Apellido,
'User_Type' =>$Type,
);
```

Y le asignas esos datos a la sesion

```
$_SESSION['User']=$log;
```

Los utilizas como coloque al principio.